# Dificulty deriving voltage reference ripple

Tags: voltage-reference, formula-derivation

I have this voltage reference circuit and I need to derive the equation that gives me the influence of \$\Delta\$Vio on the output Vref which is my Vo, I have derived the equation for Vo when \$\Delta\$Vio is not present on the circuit, at first I though that if I replaced Vz on it with Vz = (Vio + Vz + \$\Delta\$Vio) I would have my solution, but doesnt seem like it is correct, in that case Vo = (Vz + Vio + \$\Delta\$Vio)(1 + R2/R3), I dont know what I am missing here.[image]

Comment: Do you understand the output must amplify to match the Vin+ + input offset = Vin-?  There is also Zzt zener resistance that causes changes in Vout as well as thermal effects amplified.

Answer (score 0):

You've marked the output of the op-amp as \$V_{ref}\$.

The node \$V_x\$ where \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ meet is therefore:

$$
V_x = V_{ref}\frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}
$$

The inverting input of the op-amp, \$V_{-}\$, is therefore:

$$
V_{-} = V_x + V_{io}
$$
Transfer that to the non-inverting input and you get:

$$
V_Z = V_{+} = V_{-} = V_x + V_{io} = V_{ref}\frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3} + V_{io}
$$

Now essentially take the derivative of this equation:

$$
    \Delta V_Z = \frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}\Delta V_{ref} + \Delta V_{io}
$$

If you assume \$\Delta V_Z = 0\$ you get this formula for \$\Delta V_{ref}\$:

$$
\Delta V_{ref} = -\Delta V_{io}\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_3}\right)
$$

In the real world \$\Delta V_Z\$ will depend on \$\Delta V_{ref}\$ and \$V_{ref}\$, but the relationship between \$\Delta V_Z\$, \$\Delta V_{ref}\$ and \$\Delta V_{io}\$ will be as stated above.

Comment: No I get it, thank you so much.